# Playwright Percy visual comparison in local machine not working

Tags: playwright, percy

Step 1: Used the project https://github.com/percy/example-percy-playwright

Step 2: I cloned the project above to my local computer and running using VSCode
Note: I am using my office LAN and my OS is Windows

Step 3: Created a project in https://percy.io/ and generated a percy token

Step 4 : I set my percy token generated in my local windows system using the command

set PERCY_TOKEN="web..."
set PERCY_BRANCH="local"

Step 5: When I use npm run test I receive the error =>

> [percy] Skipping visual tests [percy] Error: Missing Percy token
> [percy] Running "playwright test --reporter=dot" Running 4 tests using
> 1 worker [percy] Percy is not running, disabling snapshots

Note: I TRIED IN POWERSHELL AS WELL NO LUCK

PLEASE HELP I NEED TO RUN PERCY WITH PLAYWRIGHT IN MY LOCAL WINDOWS MACHINE NONE OF THE FORUM SOLUTIONS HELPED ME

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)