# percy not running in githubActions

Tags: github, github-actions, playwright, percy

Step 1: Used the project https://github.com/aruntestrk/percy

Step 2: I cloned the project above to my local computer and running using VSCode Note: I am using my office LAN and my OS is Windows

Step 3: Created a project in https://percy.io/ and generated a percy token

Step 4 : I set my percy token generated in github secret

And now the pipeline fails with the below error:

[percy] Error: Invalid API token

Please help , you can use the code from the above github repo and can check the github actions yaml file

I set my percy token generated in github secret

And now the pipeline fails with the below error:

[percy] Error: Invalid API token

Please help , you can use the code from the above github repo and can check the github actions yaml file

Comment: How does this relate to your earlier post [Playwright Percy visual comparison in local machine not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77457335/playwright-percy-visual-comparison-in-local-machine-not-working)?

Comment: did you modify the workflow? Can you share it by updating your question, please?